# jquery replace string with regex including not

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace

I have a string, I want to replace via jquery. Let's say "foo". But it should not replace " foo" (with a space right before "foo").

How would my jquery-line look like?
This is actualy just looking for foo's:

```
$(this).replace(/foo/g, "bar");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just check there is no space before:

```
$(this).replace(/(^|\S)foo/g, "$1bar");
```

`\S` stands for any character that is not a space

```js
x = 'foo';
x = x.replace(/(^|\S)foo/, "$1bar");
console.log(x);
x = ' foo';
x = x.replace(/(^|\S)foo/, "$1bar");
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Wonderful!
Just one little question: If I want to replace "foo" with "<span>bar</span>" I get the output "<span>bar</span>" in my frontend...So it doesn't make span-elements out of my code... any idea?

Comment: @MrLumbergh:Sorry,  don't get you.Please, edit your question and add sample input strings and expected result.

Comment: Allright. I want to do this:

`$("#content h2").each(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  that.contents().each(function () {
   if (this.nodeType === 3) {
    this.nodeValue=$(this).text().replace(/(^|\S)foo/g, "$1<span class='replacedL'>f</span>oo");
   }
   if (this.nodeType===1) {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/(^|\S)foo/g, "$1<span class='replacedL'>f</span>oo") );
   }
  });
 });`

You see? I want a <span> around the "f" of "foo". :)